# How to apply the link style only to links within a block?

Tags: jquery, css

Why are all three elements highlighted when there is an exception for block with id "main"?

```css
body * :not(#main) {
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<nav><a href="link">link</a></nav>
<div>
<a href="link">link</a>
</div>
<div id="main">
<a href="link">link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Why `:not()` and not just `div a { ... }`?

Comment: Or, put a class on the element you want to have that set of styles.

Comment: In my opinion, It is more convenient when there are other blocks with links that have a different class, but most importantly, why doesn't a:not(nav a)  work?

Comment: Well, then how to select links for the style, but exclude those in nav?

Comment: "*It is more convenient when there are other blocks with links that have a different class*" It isn't really that much more convenient in the first place, but even if it was, using `not()` requires a lot more processing to apply the CSS than is necessary.

Comment: This method involves creating a new style, and this would not be desirable.

Comment: Wait  ..  so you want it to work, but you don't want to change anything?  I'll be surprised if your `nav>a` links are the default style

Comment: "*This method involves creating a new style, and this would not be desirable*" Or just replace the styles you have using `not()` with ones using a new class/selector. Or better yet, make *them* the default style and just override the `nav` css. Why is it that you think using numerous `not()` selectors is preferable than adding a class? It needs more complex selectors, is much more limited, requires more processing, is more difficult to maintain, and difficult to override. That is a *lot* of negatives just so you don't have to add a new class to replace your existing rules....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you want to do this but here is what you want.

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/Lundstromski/pen/XWdQPLj)

> Why are all three elements highlighted when there is an exception for
> block with id "main"?

It was an extra space between * and :not(main).

```
body *:not(#main)
```